# Is there a way to not allocate an elastic IP (EIP) when creating a VPC using aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I'm using the following code to create subnets that will be imported by another stack and used for a dedicated EFS VPC.   If I don't create a `PUBLIC` subnet I get errors on creation.  However the side effect is this code allocates an elastic IP address and I don't want one allocated, they are a precious resource.

How do I get rid of the elastic IP address?  None of the methods allow you get anything that has an EIP attribute or method:

```
const fileSystemVpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'vpcForEfs', {
  subnetConfiguration: [
    { 
      cidrMask: 20,
      name: 'nfsisolated',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.ISOLATED,
    },
    { 
      cidrMask: 20,
      name: 'nfsprivate',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE,
    },
    { 
      cidrMask: 20,
      name: 'nfspublic',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    },
  ],
});
```

If I comment out the `PUBLIC` section I get the following error on creation:

```
If you configure PRIVATE subnets in 'subnetConfiguration', you must also
configure PUBLIC subnets to put the NAT gateways into (got 
[{"cidrMask":20,"name":"nfsisolated","subnetType":"Isolated"},
{"cidrMask":20,"name":"nfsprivate","subnetType":"Private"}].
```

Relevant issues that don't solve the problem but are similar:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1305
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the commit that added that check: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/commit/9a96c37b225b135c9afbf523ed3fbc67cba5ca50

Essentially if CDK wasn't stopping you with that message it would fail when CloudFormation tried to deploy the stack.

Here is more info from AWS on it as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

You can see the description of the ticket that was referenced in it and the AWS docs, if whatever you want to put in the PRIVATE subnets doesn't require internet access you should be using ISOLATED instead.  This is because a PRIVATE subnet requires a NatGateway and a NatGateway is required to exist in a PUBLIC subnet with an elastic IP.  Again, if you don't require outbound access to the internet from your PRIVATE subnet just use ISOLATED

Comment: alas Lambda functions can only connect to one network, so PRIVATE has to be used.

Comment: on top of that, if you need to access the dozens of AWS resources that don't have built in gateways, your lambda function won't be able to access them without a NAT Gateway.  Bottom line:   Lambda + EFS => $30/month overhead charge for a NAT gateway